# Show that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, sum of two Cauchy sequences is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis

To show it I started off from the following:

Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so

$$
\forall \,\,\,\,\epsilon_1 >0\,\,\,\,\exists \,\,\,N_1 \in \mathbb{N}\,\,\,\ \text{such that} \,\,\,\, n,m \geq N_1 \,\,\,\, \rightarrow d(x_n,x_m) <\epsilon_1
$$
Also Let $(y_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so 
$$
\forall \,\,\,\,\epsilon_2>0 \,\,\,\,\exists \,\,\,N_2 \in \mathbb{N}\,\,\,\ \text{such that} \,\,\,\, p,q \geq N_2 \,\,\,\, \rightarrow d(y_p,y_q) <\epsilon_2
$$

Let $N=\max(N_1,N_2),r=\max(n,p),s=\max(m,q)$
Then
$$
\forall \,\,\,\,\epsilon_1>0 \,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\,\epsilon_2>0 \,\,\,\,\exists \,\,\,N \in \mathbb{N}\,\,\,\ \text{such that} \,\,\,\, r,s \geq N \,\,\,\, 
$$

$$
\rightarrow d(x_r,x_s) < \epsilon_1 \,\,\,\text{and} \,\,\,\,d(y_r,y_s)< \epsilon_2
$$

I do not know how to show $(x_n+y_n)$ be Cauchy?

If we sum them we have

$$
\rightarrow d(x_r,x_s) +d(y_r,y_s) < \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2
$$

But I need

$$
d(x_r+y_r,x_s+y_s) < \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2=\epsilon
$$

Comment: You're pretty close. Hint: What $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ can you choose  for each Cauchy sequence so that $\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 = \epsilon$? Also, you can just state that r,s $\geq$ N

Comment: Minimum of both?

Comment: Well you are given $\epsilon$ for the sequence $a_n+b_n$, so now you can choose different $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ to add up to that value. Since each sequence is Cauchy, you will get a N$_1$, N$_2$ as bounds and you proceed as you did.

Comment: Can you explain how I can get to the last line, because this is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $\epsilon$, there exists $N_1\in\Bbb N$ such that when $r,s\ge N_1$ we have that $|x_r-x_s|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}.$ Similarly, there exists $N_2\in\Bbb N$ such that $r,s\ge N_2$ implies $|y_r-y_s|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}.$

Now let $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$. So for $r,s\ge N$, we have
$$|(x_r+y_r)-(x_s+y_s)|=|(x_r-x_s)+(y_r-y_s)|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

Comment: we are not working in $\mathbb{R}$ we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$!!!

Comment: Essentially, it's the same. Just understand the $|\cdot|$ as a norm in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @Saeed If you can show where my proof is wrong, please tell me.

Comment: $x_r$ and $y_r$ live in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we cannot use absolute value as the metric.

Comment: You aren't given a topology on this either to note, but the proof is more or less the same.